# overflowed by 230 pixels in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an intro slider screen using INTRO_SLIDER flutter  Package

Here is the code ::-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/intro_slider.dart';
import 'package:intro_slider/slide_object.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: IntroScreen(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class IntroScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  IntroScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  IntroScreenState createState() => new IntroScreenState();
}

class IntroScreenState extends State<IntroScreen> {
  List<Slide> slides = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title:
        " 1stscreen ",
        maxLineTitle: 15,
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        marginDescription: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 20.0, bottom: 70.0),
        centerWidget: Text("Replace this with a custom widget", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFDAB9),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff40E0D0),
        backgroundImage: 'images/photo_eraser.png',
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topLeft,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomRight,
        onCenterItemPress: () {},
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "MUSEUM",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description: "Ye indulgence unreserved connection alteration appearance",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_museum.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFFACD),
        colorEnd: Color(0xffFF6347),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topRight,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "COFFEE",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );

    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram1",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram2",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram3",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram3",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram4",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram4",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram5",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram6",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram7",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram8",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram9",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
    slides.add(
      new Slide(
        title: "ram10",
        styleTitle:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
        description:
        "Much evil soon high in hope do view. Out may few northward believing attempted. Yet timed being songs marry one defer men our. Although finished blessing do of",
        styleDescription:
        TextStyle(color: Color(0xffD02090), fontSize: 20.0, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
        pathImage: "images/photo_coffee_shop.png",
        colorBegin: Color(0xffFFA500),
        colorEnd: Color(0xff7FFFD4),
        directionColorBegin: Alignment.topCenter,
        directionColorEnd: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        maxLineTextDescription: 3,
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget renderNextBtn() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.navigate_next,
      color: Color(0xffD02090),
      size: 35.0,
    );
  }

  Widget renderDoneBtn() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.done,
      color: Color(0xffD02090),
    );
  }

  Widget renderSkipBtn() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.skip_next,
      color: Color(0xffD02090),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new IntroSlider(
      // List slides
      slides: this.slides,

      // Skip button
      renderSkipBtn: this.renderSkipBtn(),
      colorSkipBtn: Color(0x33000000),
      highlightColorSkipBtn: Color(0xff000000),

      // Next button
      renderNextBtn: this.renderNextBtn(),

      // Done button
      renderDoneBtn: this.renderDoneBtn(),
      //onDonePress: this.onDonePress,
      colorDoneBtn: Color(0x33000000),
      highlightColorDoneBtn: Color(0xff000000),

      // Dot indicator
      colorDot: Color(0x33D02090),
      colorActiveDot: Color(0xffD02090),
      sizeDot: 13.0,

      // Show or hide status bar
      shouldHideStatusBar: true,
      backgroundColorAllSlides: Colors.grey,
    );
  }
}
```

i tried running this code for a long onboard/intro screen But this error OVERFLOWED BY PIXELS appears on the screen.

Please help me if you have solution for this error.If you need more details then please comment. I don't think if you need more code as i have added all the necessary codes

[image]

HERE IS THE CONSOLE REPORT:-

```
A RenderFlex overflowed by 80 pixels on the right.

User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Stack file:///C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intro_slider-2.2.8/lib/intro_slider.dart:826:28
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#902c4 relayoutBoundary=up4 OVERFLOWING
...  parentData: not positioned; offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=160.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
...  size: Size(160.0, 8.0)
...  direction: horizontal
...  mainAxisAlignment: center
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  textDirection: ltr
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/SurfaceView(22059): 252759636 windowPositionLostRT RT, frameNr = 0
```

Comment: try reducing size of the dot and check whether it got fixed

Comment: I minimized to smallest size possible but error is not disappearing.Please look at console report I have added.

Comment: Just have a look what I have got when I reduce the dot size https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTLWy.png

Comment: It worked now. I reduced point size to  4

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap that section in `Expanded()` like this

```
 Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(),
  ],
);
```

Comment: ``return MaterialApp(
      home:  Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(child:IntroScreen(),),
        ],
      )
      

    );``

Comment: I think flexible widget will be fit for this

Comment: I did it but same error appears.I think the problem is  with dot size not with contents

Comment: Please check the console report i added